# Why do I get a MultiValueDictKeyError everytime I try to get the data from a POST request?

Tags: javascript, python, django, http

I'm currently learning in Django, and in this fetch request, I always get the same error. How could I avoid it?

topup.html

```
            let data = new FormData();

            data.append('amount', document.getElementById('amount').value);

            data.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', "{{ csrf_token }}");



            var response = fetch('{% url "secret" %}', {
              method: 'POST',
              body: data,
              credentials: 'same-origin',

            })
```

views.py

```
def secret(request):
    amount = request.POST["amount"]
```

error:

MultiValueDictKeyError at /secret
'amount'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/secret
Django Version: 3.0.6
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:
'amount'
Exception Location: C:\Users\eric3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py in **getitem**, line 78
Python Executable:  C:\Users\eric3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.2

[Django Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnbjW.jpg)

I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `MultiValueDictKeyError` exception when opening that URL, because when `request.POST["amount"]` is evaluated, it founds no item within the POST dictionary with a key named `'amount'`.

Apparently, you want `secret` view to be a view that is going to be reached only through ajax calls, not to be accessed by the user. If you don't want that, to get rid of that exception being raised when non-ajax requests reach the view, then do the following:

```
def secret(request):
    amount = request.POST.get("amount")
    # ... all your other code
```

Now it doesn't matter if your view is accessed by a user or by an ajax call, that exception is gone.

On the other hand, the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/) advises to use the canonical csrf token included in the cookies, when performing **POST method** requests through ajax. Make sure that you have put `'X-CSRFToken'` within the HTTP request headers to do so.

The JavaScript code should look more or less as follows:

```
/* Create FormData instance and append the field that you want */
let data = new FormData();
data.append('amount', document.getElementById('amount').value);

/* Perform the fetch call */
fetch("{% url 'secret' %}", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
    headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken}
    })
    /* Do whatever you do when a response (successful or not) has been received */
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })


/* Get csrf cookie */
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

As said in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/), you can simplify a lot the process of getting the cookie by using the [JavaScript Cookie Library](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/)

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, when I use on the serverside request.POST.get("amount"), the object I get is None. I don't know why :(

Comment: Even substituting the part of "getelementbyid" directly by a constant, for example "5", in django, "amount" always has the value of None.

Comment: How are you accessing that `secret` view? If you are going to this URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/secret` in your browser, you're going to get `None` assigned to the `amount` variable because that's the default behavior of the `request.POST.get(key)` function when it doesn't find any item in the dictionary (in this case, the dictionary is POST) with the given key (in this case, the key is 'amount'). How do you actually want to access this view? By the user going to the URL, or to be requested by an AJAX call?

Comment: Basically, that view is accessed by an AJAX call from the script of `topup.html`. In that page, the user introduces in an input field (with `id="amount"` an amount, and then through fetch I send that request to the `secret` view, that seems that doesn't find the key 'amount'. Why do you think this is happening?

Comment: What does `console.log(response)` print? What are you returning in your `secret` view?

Comment: Well, I get a 500 code, because in the `secret` view I need the `amount` value in order to generate a Stripe payment intent, for getting the secret key I need for start the payment processing in `topup.html`. The problem is that the `amount` value isn't retrieved by django using `request.POST.get("amount")`, it's like the key wouldn't exist. But curiously, the csrf token it's correctly retreived, and they're both in the same FormData, as I showed before. I'm trying everything, but I don't know what else I can do. The `secret` view returns jsonresponse with the stripe secret key I would get.

Comment: How are you getting the CSRF token in your view, if it was removed from the Form Data? Just to be positive: Are you trying the solution I gave just as I suggested? Try printing `print(request.POST)` and check your terminal (where you entered `python manage.py runserver`) immediately after you perform the AJAX call. You should see something like: `<QueryDict: {'amount': ['whatever']}>`

Comment: That's what I get printing the request in the terminal: `<QueryDict: {'amount': ['5'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['yf13NBsIOF6mCHd07VxonMAc7HEHlObeYxKF1Ew01ai4412IOWThEPumd6fPJ0dm']}>`
I get the CSRF token into the view inside the Form Data, it has not been removed in any moment.

Comment: But in the 500 django error page, when I check there the local variables, it indicates me that the value of `request` is `<WSGIRequest: GET '/secret'>`. I don't know why.
Btw, thank you really much for helping me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: It proves that you're indeed receiving the desired payload in your views when performing the ajax call. The 500 error that you're receiving in the ajax response, must be coming from other part of your code. If you paste this in your view: `print("AMOUNT: ", request.POST.get('amount'))`, and then perform the ajax call, and immediately after you check your terminal, you are going to see `AMOUNT: 5` there.

Comment: No problem, buddy. I'm glad to help.

Comment: Yeah, effectively printing that line returns in the terminal `AMOUNT: 5`, but just the next line, is `total = int(float(amount) * 100)` , and in the Django 500 error debug page, it indicates me `float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'`. And then:
`Local variables: amount -> value: None` |
`print("AMOUNT: ", request.POST.get('amount'))` is line 24 | 
`amount = request.POST.get('amount')` is line 25 | 
`total = int(float(amount) * 100)` is line 26 <- Where django raises the TypeError I described before.
Don't you think it could be an error of Django in my machine?

Comment: The thing is that you're going to always get that error when accessing to that URL in your browser, because obviously if you do so you're not passing any POST data. So Django debug page is not really telling you anything important if there's any other error in your code, because it's going to complain only for this line -> `total = int(float(amount) * 100)`, as amount will be `None` in that case (because of the aforementioned reason). So you should not focus on that, but on what you receive inside the `.then()` function in your JS code, as it is what the ajax calls gets responded with.

Comment: We already know that the ajax call is passing the desired information, as you check that when printed what I told you before. Hence, we're sure that if you're getting a 500 error code in the response of that call, must be due to another part of your code.

Comment: You were right. I was opening the response from the Chrome inspector, and rather than showing me the preview of the response, if I double click it just creates another GET request in another tab.